# how to load an immediate value to the register in arm64?

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, arm64, mov

I want to load an immediate value (0x48f0d0) to the register x0, but I have an error "Assembler messages:

```
/tmp/ccUzTnfa.s:257: Error: immediate cannot be moved by a single instruction"
```

this is the instruction I used:

```
mov x0, #0x48f0d0
```

Comment: If you need it to be an immediate then you can't do with a single instruction. You could use multiple, or go the normal way using a literal pool with `ldr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only [certain constants](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220808-00/?p=106953) can be expressed as immediate operands on ARM64.  To work around this restriction, either load from a literal pool

```
ldr x0, =0x48f0d0
```

or use a `movz`/`movk` pair:

```
movz x0, #0xf0d0
movk x0, #0x48, lsl #16
```